# Link from cell in other sheet shows 0 but other sheet shows data cant get past this

Tags: vba, excel

Spent hours searching for any mention of this but no luck.  Maybe someone here knows the answer. I developed a large application in excel. sheet1 receives data from a Com server that just places it there. This has been working for a long time with no problems.
I have sheet2 two with links from sheet 1 and formulas. Mostly I do all the processing in sheet1 change event because I got circular refernces when putting functions in a cell. 
From yesterday, I have a problem that the cell in sheet 2 shows 0. When I go to the linked cell it has data. Sometimes numbers and sometimes text depending, but sheet 2 shows 0.

As well as the linked cells, I also screen scrape some data with a seperate process and place it sheet 3 to link across to other cells, so sheet2 will also contain links form this data. I spent today changing this so it places the data in directly in sheet1 instead of creating links. This is tedious and will cause other problems.
I checked options -> formulas.  Right now it is set at max iterations 100; max change 100. I had reduced max iterations to stop some functions firing themselves recursively through the sheet change event. Now I raised it back to 100.
I deleted all the data saved the sheet started again and the same thing happened again.
e.g. sheet1 cell "A1" has a value of 10
sheet2 cell a1 has a formula of ='sheet1'!A1
sheet 2 cell A1 is showing 0
when I look in the formula bar I see the formula

This data was damaged down to row 42 the last row that had held data. below that the conditional formatting was the correct color even though the formulas looked identical and i could see nothing wrong to explain it, I dragged the formula from 44 upwards again and everything worked, but bizarrely, when I copied from sheet1 cells 1 to 44 and pasted a link back in, I still got 0.
When I run the system and the COM erver delivers a load and the change event fires etc, I end up back with the same problem.

Now when I add a new sheet and paste my links from sheet1 into this, it works as it should.
Right now after my attempts to fix it. All sheet1 and sheet2 columns are formatted general  though previousy I had one column text and some others number. I can't control the format of sheet1 because excel just adapts to the data it receives regardless what I do.
I also keep checkng for application.enableevents and this is not the problem nor is worksheet calculate and in the options I have automatic claculation set
The only other routine running under sheet change in sheet 2 is a tidyup that clears out old data after the COM server has delivered a smaller number of rows.
It copies default data from unused cells in the sheet. I placed the right formatting and default such as blank or 0 depending on what is required. This has not in the past caused any issues and I cant see what it might do, though previously when I just tried puttng "" in the cells to be cleared that did cause nasty excel erros. but not now.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: There's no way for us to make serious suggestions with no idea of *exactly* what you're doing.  If you have code then it always helps to post the relevant parts of it.  Since you mention the sheet having been "damaged" then a good start would be to copy it all to a fresh sheet and see if that fixes things.

Comment: Thanks Tim. Theresa lot of code to be pasting in. I cant see ho it would help without  pinpointing somewhere to start.

Comment: When I say damaged, I mean the 0 showing up instead of correct data.

I have sen somethng suspicious but not sure how to track it down. 
After running the change event deliberately a few times for debugging, I notice I have two mii screens above the task bar as normal. One for the workbook and one for the VBA IDE, but now they are joined by two greyed out mini screens that dont respond to clicking. I suspect that somewhere in the sheet it has created a link to a previous repaiered/recovered thin from one of the crashes. Maybe my links are really pointing at this shell of an application?

Comment: 1. We're not going to help you if you don't provide some proof of effort (code snipplet). 2. Your textual description is way too long to be worth reading. 3. I think your issue is data type nature, make sure you don't check e.g. numbers agains texts.

Comment: 4. If it's a change event how on Earth do you debug it? I suggest you transfering the Change event's sub end create a, say, `Sub ertdfgcvb(Target As Range)`. Then your change event Will use `Call ertdfgcvb, Target` and you can finally debug with say `Sub dfg() Call ertdfgcvb, Range("A1")`. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks @user3819867,
That's exactly ho it is set up and I have a button on the speed meu to fire it for debugging. I used to just put a breakpoint in the forst line.
There's a lot of code doing different stuff ,I promise you the detailed information is a lot quicker and easier to read.  That's why I need t aclue about what code to show. For that matter, I too still suspect data types though I dont know whta to look for next and this is not necessarily a code thing.
In any case, How would I upload code? This is a small  edit box

Comment: Well just so others may have visibility when this happens to them.
I rebuilt everything on a new blank workbook restructured code a little to remove all formulas form cells and do calculation in the vba run by change event. Today after exhaustive testing, it was a joy to watch. For testing I had one set of old data in the data store sheet and kept changing a 1 or 2 to the title to force the change event and see the app rebuild itself. Great.

Comment: I connected to the com server and got fresh data into store sheet: then all links to my working sheet dont change, Copy a link to a n empty cell from a text cell and it produces 0 in the dest. cell
Copy the same link to any new sheet and it displays perfectly, but links wont work anywhere in my working sheet.I planned the data types exhaustively and verything is still in synch. double to double general to general.  If I add a sheet I can paste any link into default cll and it works. Nota data type issue surely???

Comment: I am guessing something in the sheet (not the workboo) has switched off calcualtion or events or something.
Formulas are still set to auto in options
?application.enableevents  produces true

Surely someone out there has a clue??

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is still relevant, but I had the same issue and came here searching for an answer.

In my case, I realized the cell I was trying to copy was a merged cell (i.e. it provided a range) the formula was [='Sheet1'!B10:N10] and the result was 0 and not the text I wanted. so I changed the formula to ='USA-CA'!B10 and it worked.

hope this is helpful to someone else.

Comment: This worked. Don’t know why it isn’t just an error condition.

Answer (score 0):

This little routine fixes it.
Sub fixformulas()
'fix formulas broken by excel for some reason
    Cells.Replace What:="=", Replacement:="=", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder _
        :=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
End Sub

All I can work out is that when excel copies the formulas and puts them back in place it corrupts the equals sign. Everything else is fine but as oon as I replace this the lights go on.

I'd rather know how to prevent it, but I hope nobody else suffers like I have.